# Parsing non-standard date string from Stack Overflow into a .NET DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, screen-scraping

I'm writing a screen-scraper for Stack Overflow. The bit I'm writing now takes the HTML and puts all the information into a model object. I've run into a bit of bother while parsing the information from an answer.

The problem is the date format that StackOverflow uses to describe absolute times. [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) doesn't work on them. I've tried fooling around with [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) but I've had no success. Both throw a [`FormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception.aspx)

Here's some background:

If you look at the source HTML for an answer, you get this:

```
<div id="answer-{id}" class="answer">
    <!-- ... -->
            answered <span title="2009-06-18 13:21:16Z UTC" class="relativetime">Jun 18 at 13:21</span>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Notice that the absolute time is stored in the span's title attribute. I've used the [HTML Agility Pack](http://codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) from CodePlex to access the elements, and have extracted the value of the attribute.

Now I'm wondering how to get the `"2009-06-18 13:21:16Z UTC"` into a .NET [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) object.

I'd like to be able to do this without Regexes, etc., but as the whole project is hackish and unstable, I don't really mind!

Finally, I can't use the data dump for these reasons:

1. I can't use BitTorrent. Ever.
2. If I could, the files are too big for my net connection.
3. It's a bit out of date.
4. It's not as fun!

Comment: Because of this question a Bug report was added to Meta.StackOverflow.com http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/data-dump-formats-time-incorrectly

Comment: You may want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/api/userquestions.html?userid=41981&page=1&pagesize=10&sort=recent and http://stackoverflow.com/api/userquestions.json?userid=41981&page=1&pagesize=10&sort=recent **`Warning`**: Consider these urls **pre-alpha**, there has been **no** mention of these by the sites authors.

Comment: @Brad Gilbert: Thanks for the bug report; I was thinking of one but thought it might be bydesign. Good to know it's not just me who thinks its a bug ;). Also, the JSON queries seem interesting - I'll take a closer look when I get round to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"Z"` and `"UTC"` in the same `DateTime` string seems redundant.

If you remove `"UTC"` from the string, `Parse` works:

```
System.DateTime.Parse("2009-06-18 13:21:16Z")
{18.06.2009 15:21:16}
    Date: {18.06.2009 00:00:00}
    Day: 18
    DayOfWeek: Thursday
    DayOfYear: 169
    Hour: 15
    Kind: Local
    Millisecond: 0
    Minute: 21
    Month: 6
    Second: 16
    Ticks: 633809352760000000
    TimeOfDay: {15:21:16}
    Year: 2009
```

Comment: Thanks for that - it works perfectly. I'm kicking myself though ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you'd never use regex for this, but I think that format is just "u" described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

So ParseExact should accept that (with some minor work).

Comment: Why is the UTC even there, though?  Doesn't Z imply Zulu or UTC?  Seems like it ought to be omitted.

Comment: Just remove it. I don't know enough about timezones to comment on the difference between 'Zulu' and 'UTC' :)

Comment: Yes, "Z" and "UTC" refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I havn't found the magic to match the timezone (Z UTC) here, but assuming they're all UTC, this should get you started:

```
   string d = "2009-06-18 13:21:16Z UTC";
   CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
   string format  = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ UTC";
   DateTime dt ;
   if(DateTime.TryParseExact(d,format,provider,DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal,out dt) {
          //use dt;
   } else {
       //bail out, error.
   }
```